# Converting a padded string to a number in c#

Tags: c#

I am using the following code:

```
string new = old.Substring(0,2).TrimStart('0') + "." + old.Substring(2,2).TrimStart('0');
```

to convert as follows:

```
0101 >> 1.1
99.10 >> 99.1
99.01 >> 99.01
```

The problem is that the following conversion does not work correctly:

```
0100 >> 1.0
```

Is there an easy way I could fix this. I can't understand why it does not convert correctly. It's important for me to have the ".0" after the one. When I run the above all I see is "1."

Comment: have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711264/most-efficient-way-to-convert-a-string-to-2-decimal-places-in-c-sharp

Comment: Your translations seem inconsistent.  How does 0101 translate to 1.1?  shouldn't it be 1.01?  Are you assuming 2 decimal places?

Comment: The number to the left of the decimal and the number to the right are not related. So 45.25 >> 4525 and 10.01 >> 0101.

Comment: It'd help if you told us the rules of how the numbers translated.  Even your comment doesn't match the original question for 0101.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TrimStart will always remove ALL 0s that the string starts with.  So your second part ends up being:

```
"00".TrimStart('0')
```

which will always yield empty string.

Try this instead to ensure you always get that 0:

```
string new = old.Substring(0,2).TrimStart('0') + "." + 
             old.Substring(2,2).TrimStart('0').PadLeft(1, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you call Int32.TryParse() then divide by 100?

```
string s = "0101";
int n;
if(int.TryParse(s, out n))
{
  decimal d = n / 100M;
  string x = d.Format("f2");
}
```